# Fixing bash script

Tags: linux, bash

Currently, I am struggling getting 2 codes working in my bash script.
They both work separately, but once they are both in the code, they don't.

```
var=$(cat /sys/block/vda/queue/rotational 2>/dev/null || cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational 2>/dev/null)
dtype='nil'
if [ $var = 0 ]; then
dtype=' SSD '
elif [ $var = 1 ]; then
        dtype=' HDD '
fi


var1=$(lsmod | grep kvm | awk 'NR==1{print $3}'  2>/dev/null)
vtype = 'no'
if [ $var1 = 0 ]; then
        vtype=' no '
else
    vtype = 'yes'
fi

printf '$dtype' '$vtype'
echo $dtype $vtype
```

First variable `var` is supposed to hold the value of rotational file. Asks `0` is for SSD and `1` is for HDD.

The second variable `var1` checks if virtualization is present in your machine. 
If the number it holds is `0`, then `vtype` is set to `no`, if its something else, then `vtype` is set to `yes`.
These commands work perfectly, if i do them on different code files. But i need them both together. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is not working

Comment: The `printf` command at the end is wrong.  The first argument should be a format string. Try `printf '%s %s\n' "$dtype" "$vtype"` (note also the choice of quotes here).

Comment: `=` must no be surrounded by space (when assigning that is)

Comment: See https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Thanks @Kusalananda your printf worked better and the shellcheck helped also, will use it more now as i did not know of it before.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are four main issues in this script:

1. The `#!`-line at the top is missing. As far as I can see, this can be `#!/bin/sh`.
2. Variable expansions are unquoted.  Use double quotes to avoid word-splitting and filename globbing.  For example, `if [ "$var" = 0 ]`.  Here you may also choose to use `-eq` in place of `=` since you're doing an arithmetic test.
3. Assignments must not have spaces around `=`.
4. The first argument of `printf` should be a format string, for example `printf '%s %s\n' "$dtype" "$vtype"`.

These things may be found using [the ShellCheck site](https://www.shellcheck.net/).

There is also a minor inefficiency:

```
lsmod | grep kvm | awk 'NR==1{print $3}'  2>/dev/null
```

could be written, almost equivalently,

```
lsmod | awk '/kvm/ { print $3; exit }'
```

I'm not sure why you put spaces in the values of some of the variables, e.g. `dtype=' HDD '`.

Comment: Note that a _missing `#!`_ is the POSIX way to write POSIX scripts (though I'd tend to agree using `#! /bin/sh -` is preferable, at least on systems where `/bin/sh` is a POSIX shell)